# Is it possible to pass a model to a layout in Express?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I know that it is possible to pass a model to a view in express by doing something like this:

```
exports.locations = function(req, res){
    Location.find(function(err, results) {
        res.render('locations', { title: 'Locations', locations: results });
    });
};
```

But is it possible to pass a model to my layout?

Comment: When you say your "layout" to you mean for example your generic 'layout.jade' which you are extending with `extends layout` inside your view? If so, your layout has access to the model you pass in to `render()`. Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: No, you are correct. There are documents I would like to access for every view as part of the layout, and right now I am having to pass those documents in every route. Is there an easier way to do that?

Comment: So is what you are really asking is if there is a way to have a 'template' model object, so to speak, prepopulated with a few 'global' items, and which you would only need to extended with your page-specific content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have all (relevant) routes inside a single .js file, you could add a function like this:

```
function applyGlobals(pageModel) {
    pageModel.myGlobalThing = "I'm always available";
    pageModel.anotherGlobalThing = 8675309;
    return(pageModel);
}


exports.locations = function(req, res){
    Location.find(function(err, results) {
        res.render('locations', applyGlobals({ title: 'Locations', locations: results }));
    });
};
```

You could also create a more generalizable solution:

```
function Globalizer(baseContent) {

    var theFunc = function(specificContent) {
        var keys = Object.keys(baseContent);
        for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++)
        {
            //  the lets the page content override global content by not
            //  overwriting it if it exists;
            if(!specificContent.hasOwnProperty(keys[i])){
                specificContent[keys[i]] = baseContent[keys[i]];
            }
        }
        return specificContent;
    };
    return theFunc;
};

// And use it like so.

var applyGlobals = new Globalizer({global1: 12, global2: 'otherthing'});

var pageVars = applyGlobals({item1: 'fifteen', 'item2': 15, global2: 'override'});
console.log(require('util').inspect(pageVars));
```

Which would emit:

```
{ item1: 'fifteen',
  item2: 15,
  global2: 'override',
  global1: 12 }
```

Similarly, you could use one of the various `mixin`, `extend` `assign` or similar functions of various libraries like lodash, underscore, etc. See the [doc for `lodash.assign()`](http://lodash.com/docs#assign) which illustrates accomplishing the same sort of thing.

**UPDATE** One more way of doing it.

You might want to check out Express' [`app.locals` documentation](http://expressjs.com/3x/api.html#app.locals) as well - it might work well for you.

Comment: You are very welcome; glad it was helpful. Note that I had just posted an edit mentioning Express' `app.locals` as another approach too. Have a great week.